# How does one find and replace text in all open files with kate?

Tags: search, replace, kate

How does one find and replace text **in all open files** with [kate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kate_%28text_editor%29)?

Comment: I'm not sure that you currently can. replace was only recently added, and I don't see that you can do a find/replace in more than one file at a time.

Comment: Is this some kind of bot generating random 'how does one find and replace text in all open files with $EDITOR'??

Comment: @axel He originally asked them [all in one question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7921/how-does-one-find-and-replace-text-in-all-open-files-with-geany-gedit-jed-kate), and it got closed. Several of us said (in insufficiently discouraging tones) that if he really needs to know in five different editors he should ask five questions, so he did

Comment: I am unable to tap my magic wand to cause all of the people that I advise and support to use the OS distribution and editors of my own choosing. Advising most of them to use the command line with something like find would not support one of my objectives of promoting Linux over MS Windows. So, knowing the functionality of multiple editors is useful.

Comment: FWIW, Kate is getting a brand new search and replace plugin for KDE 4.8 that can find and replace in all open files or any arbitrary directory.  You can try it out in KDE 4.8 Beta 1 or [by building Kate from source](http://kate-editor.org/get-it/) if you'd like.

Answer (score 11):

In Kate 3.8.5-

Go to *Settings* -> *Configure Kate* -> *Plugins* and enable there *Search & Replace*. Then use the "Search and Replace" button that appears at the bottom of the Kate main window to find the desired functionality.

Comment: This answer applies also to Kate 3.13.2 (KDE Development Platform 4.13.2)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple. As of Kate 3.4.3 (present in KDE 4.4.3) you **can not** replace in multiple files at once but just in the one you're currently viewing calling "edit->replace" or with the CTRL+R shortcut.

Comment: Figures.  KDE is notorious for taking things that work and making them not so.

Answer (score 2):

In at least this Kate version (built from source):

[image]

but I think some older versions have this too, you can add a **plugin** called "**Search and Replace**" (in Settings, Configure Kate, Plugins)

[image]

that has these, **in Current file**, **in Open files**, **in Folder** options:

[image]